# How to interpret low R^2 value when we have the whole population

Tags: regression, linear-model, r-squared

I am predicting the performance in a subject given the percentage of a gender that is in a group, for example, a group might be 70% female and 30% male. There is a significant relationship (p < 0.01) between more females and worse performance for this particular subject, but the R^2 value is very low (0.01, i.e. % of females in the class explains 1% of the variance).

I have the whole population for this dataset, does this make a difference when interpreting R^2? Should I still report these figures?

[image: Linear models that I'm investigating]

Putting this into a graph looks impressive and makes me think I should be reporting it, as -1 grade is a substantial difference here.

[image]

Comment: I don't think that having the whole population changes the understanding/interpretation of r squared at all. It's still the explained variance of your model. If many things influence the overall variance and only a few are in your model, your explained variance will remain small. What having the population would change, to me, is the importance of your p values. If you know the whole population than the effect size you find is the real effect size.

Comment: Can you please explain your dependent variable more? It's not clear how class performance/Grade_difference is measured. That is likely to explain why your model has such low explanatory power.

Comment: grade difference is the difference between the grade in subject X and a students average grade in all other subjects.

Comment: What is your story for believing that proportion of females in a subject determines the performance relative the mean in all other subjects? It doesn't seem like a sound argument to me. It seems that subject difficulty would have much more explanatory power, though I'm not sure how you could measure that.

Comment: A good question. It's building on other STEM work where lower numbers of females are seen to get worse results than female only classes. None of that research appears to be built on rigorous statistical models though... And maybe they are overclaiming

Comment: Well your regression indicates that proportion in a subject that are females has almost no explanatory power in explaining variation in grade difference across subjects. It sounds like the work you mentioned is very misleading, as they don't have a story to motivate the causation.

Comment: Say I am testing economic growth. And I know, somehow, that X influences that so its effect size is real (and would be statistically significant). It could still have a very small R squared value if many other variables also influenced economic growth, which is likely. R squared and effect size are, potentially, very different realities.

Comment: would it be fair to say that % female and grade difference are correlated, but there are other factors involved in explaining the correlation?

Comment: Maybe males choose to enroll in easier classes.

Comment: Based on a thorough review of recent professional journal articles in the area of regression analysis - and statistics in general - the term most frequently used to describe analytical results with R-squared values of 0.01 is "poopy-doopy".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the whole population, the use of P-values and CIs is questionable because these are used for inference and estimation, but you don't need to do those things if you have the population. R-squared would have it's usual interpretation as far as I am aware (percentage of variation in the DV explained by the multiple regression model with x1, x2,...xn).

Comment: That is what I have always felt (I normally work with whole populations). Some argue that even with whole populations p values may matter, because your population can be conceived of as a sample of a larger population (for example of one state of the whole country or that chronologically as it could change over time).

Comment: I think a more interesting question is, say it isn't part of a larger population of interest, but did you actually obtain the population? Did you have accidental inclusion or exclusion or some measurement error that introduces uncertainty that maybe a CI would help illustrate? Or even, is the population stagnant through time and you only care about this exact group you've obtained? If not, a p-value or CI would still be relevant even if you have the true population at this instant in time.

Comment: I work, in this case, with closed cases, and there is considerable effort to be sure the data is accurate as the case closes because it has to be reported to the federal government. That said I am sure there are errors in the data although probably a small amount for most measures. It is certainly the whole population - that it is every customer we served (it must be by law).,